# auto populate cells based on drop-down selection

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that I would like to be able to auto-populate "lists" based on a drop-down selection. For example, A1 has a drop-down menu for all the departments in my company. We have different "to-do" list for each department (inserted through multiple rows on a second sheet). Is there a way to easily make it so that If I choose the (i.e.) HR department, the HR to-do list will auto-populate on the rows B7 and on, or if I choose the IT department, then the IT to-do list will auto-populate? I know I can do it with vlookup, but since each department has a different list, with different amount of items, I'm trying to find an easier way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use the worksheet_change event to trigger fetching the relevant list based on the selected value - try that, then post back with your code if you run into specific problems.

Comment: Thank you! I still couldn't figure out who to get it to work so I ended up using a huge IF formula to return range.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example based on `MATCH()` and `INDEX()`

say the categories are in column **A** and the data validation pull-down that references these categories is in cell **B1**.

Associated with each category is a list and the lists are located in a table in columns **D** through **F**:

[image]

In **C1** enter the formula:

```
=INDEX($D$1:$F$4,ROWS($1:1),MATCH($B$1,A:A,0))
```

and copy downward.

Then when we select a category in **B1**, the associated list will appear in column **C**:

[image]